# Querying 3 tables mysql Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, relational-database, laravel, laravel-3

I have multiple tables.

- Contests
- Entries
- Users

User can submit entries to a contest, a user can submit multiple entries to a contest.

I need to know the emails of the users that submitted an entry to a particular contest. The emails are in the user table.

Getting all the entries from a contest isn't that hard, I accomplish this by:

```
$entries = Contest::find(1)->entries()->first();
```

Now I have all the entries belonging to the contest with an id of 1(for example use). Now, how do I get all the user emails from my users table in an efficient manner?

So three tables that are linked, I start with the contest id then get all the entries from that contest and then need to get all the user emails wich I haven't been able to get yet.

Hopefully this makes sense. If not, ask away!

Comment: What about [eager loading](http://four.laravel.com/docs/eloquent#eager-loading)? Like so: `Contest::with('entries.users')->get()->first();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$getUser = Contest::find(1)->users()->get();
$getEmails = $getUser->email;

foreach($getEmails as $getEmail)
    echo $getEmail;
```

You'll get all the user `emails` corresponding to the `contest` id 1. But first you must do the database relation in `model` to get this to work.

Comment: This doesn't work because I'm getting: SQL: SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `contest_id` = ?  And my users table obviously doesn't have a contest_id column. Or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Probably easier to use the Query Builder in this case instead of Eloquent:

```
// Get array of users that submitted entries to contest ID 45
$users = DB::table('contests AS c')
  ->join('entries AS e','e.contest_id','=','c.id')
  ->join('users AS u','e.user_id','=','u.id')
  ->where('c.id','=',45) // Contest ID
  ->get();

//or get an array of emails:
$users = DB::table('contests AS c')
  ->join('entries AS e','e.contest_id','=','c.id')
  ->join('users AS u','e.user_id','=','u.id')
  ->where('c.id','=',45) // Contest ID
  ->lists('email');
```

In Laravel, Eloquent is not always the best decision for everything. Sometimes Query Builder is better/easier. Eloquent is more convenient for simple functionality and relationships.